# Android app keeps crashing in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am making my first android app.
Android Studio shows no error in the code.
However, the app keeps crashing as soon as I try to launch it in the Emulator.
I am using the inbuilt Nexus 5X API 23 for the emulator.
Please help me?
Thank you!

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.coursebrowser">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.admin.coursebrowser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout myLayout= new RelativeLayout(this);
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    Button redButton= new Button(this);
    redButton.setText("Click Me");
    redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    myLayout.addView(redButton);
    setContentView(myLayout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.admin.coursebrowser.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-10 15:09:23.291 3442-3442/com.example.admin.coursebrowser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.admin.coursebrowser, PID: 3442
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.coursebrowser/com.example.admin.coursebrowser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.admin.coursebrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.example.admin.coursebrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
```

You do not have a `FloatingActionButton`, let alone one named `R.id.fab`, in your `RelativeLayout`. You are not using the `activity_main.xml` file in your Java code.

Comment: I do not want to use the activity_main.xml file. I just want to create a layout in JAVA, and use that. I just posted the xml file here because it existed in Android Studio.
How do I fix the FloatingActionButton error?

Comment: @kudesiaji: Then get rid of the Java code that is referring to the `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `setContentView(myLayout);` change this to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`